# Getting the wrong answer when dividing two integers, one large and one small

Tags: python, python-3.x, scientific-notation

I am attempting to use a prime sieve to find all the prime factors of certain numbers. In my code, I end up having to divide a very large number by a small number to find a prime factor that is out of the range of the sieve I'm using. This shouldn't be a problem, in fact, the method works perfectly for every number I checked except for one.

The problem I have run into is that I divide this large number by 51 to find the prime factor and then when I multiply it by 51 to check if it equals the original number... IT DOESN'T!!

It does not work regardless of if I convert it to an int or if I leave it as a float in scientific notation.

I understand that floats are not perfect, but I don't know how to get around this weird error. I even plugged the numbers into a calculator and got the correct answer, but my code gives me the wrong answer.

What is going on here?
If you run my code you will see that the checks return False when they should be True for both.

As I said before, this method WORKS for one of the numbers I am testing that has a factor outside the range of the sieve I am using, it is only this specific large number that I am having issues with.

The correct answer should be 1,176,462,117,668,023,508,828,242,241
and the answer im getting is 1,176,462,117,668,023,481,334,235,136

```
l_number = 59999568001069198950240354291
answer = 59999568001069198950240354291 / 51
int_answer = int(answer)
check = int_answer*51
check2 = answer * 51

print("The large number is: {:,d}".format(l_number))
print("Large number divided by 51: ", answer)
print("If the check is == original number: ", check2 == 59999568001069198950240354291)
print("Large number divided by 51 as an integer: {:,d}".format(int_answer))
print("That answer * 51 (should be original number): {:,d}".format(check))
print("If the integer check is == original number: ", check == 59999568001069198950240354291)
```

Comment: I hope you have a good sieve. The next prime factor of that number (after 3 & 17) is 143047654201

Comment: The method finds the factors 3 and 17 and then multiplies them together to get 51, and then divides the original number by 51 to get the last prime factor.

Comment: I am using the parameter of 1e7 for the sieve and any additional factors larger than that are found by multiplying the known prime factors together and dividing into the number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you point out float division is not exact due to the limited precision available to a 64-bit double.

It works if you use integer division (in Python 3)

```
answer = 59999568001069198950240354291 // 51
```

This works because Python uses arbitrary precision integer arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you very much. As you can see I am still new to learning Python, you have helped me very much here!!!!